# conditional FilterSets in DRF 3.7 autogen docs: can I add a queryparam filter for a route (but only for certain HTTP verbs)

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

(DRF v3.7, django-filters v1.1.0)

Hi!  I have a working FilterSet that lets me filter my results via a query parameter, e.g. `http://localhost:9000/mymodel?name=FooOnly`

This is working just fine.

```
class MyNameFilter(FilterSet):
    name = CharFilter(field_name='name', help_text='Filter by name')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name',)


class MyModel(...):
    ...
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = MyNameFilter
```

But when I render the built-in auto-generated docs for my API, I am seeing this query parameter documented for all methods in my route, e.g. `GET`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, etc.

I only intend to filter via this query parameter for some of these HTTP verbs, as it doesn't make sense for others, e.g. `PUT`

Is there a good way to make my FilterSet conditional in this manner?  Conditional on route method.

I tried applying this logic at both the Router level (a misguided idea). Also at the ViewSet level -- but there is no `get_filter_class` override method in the same way there is e.g. `get_serializer_class`.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out, with help from Carlton G. on the django-filters Google Groups forum (thank you, Carlton).

My solution was to go up a level and intercept the CoreAPI schema that came out of the AutoSchema inspection, but before it made its way into the auto-generated docs.

At this point of interception, I override `_allows_filters` to apply only on my HTTP verbs of interest.  (Despite being prefixed with a `_` and thus intended as a private method not meant for overriding, the method's comments explicitly encourage this.  `Introduced in v3.7: Initially "private" (i.e. with leading underscore) to allow changes based on user experience.`

My code below:

```
from rest_framework.schemas import AutoSchema


# see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#autoschema
#     and https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

class LimitedFilteringViewSchema(AutoSchema):
    # Initially copied from lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/schemas/inspectors.py:352,
    # then modified to restrict our filtering by query-parameters to only certain view
    # actions or HTTP verbs
    def _allows_filters(self, path, method):
        if getattr(self.view, 'filter_backends', None) is None:
            return False

        if hasattr(self.view, 'action'):
            return self.view.action in ["list"]  # original code:  ["list", "retrieve", "update", "partial_update", "destroy"]

        return method.lower() in ["get"]  # original code:  ["get", "put", "patch", "delete"]
```

And then, at my APIView level:

```
class MyViewSchema(LimitedFilteringViewSchema):

    # note to StackOverflow:  this was some additional schema repair work I 
    # needed to do, again adding logic conditional on the HTTP verb.  
    # Not related to the original question posted here, but hopefully relevant
    # all the same.

    def get_serializer_fields(self, path, method):
        fields = super(MyViewSchema, self).get_serializer_fields(path, method)

        # The 'name' parameter is set in MyModelListItemSerializer as not being required.
        # However, when creating an access-code-pool, it must be required -- and in DRF v3.7, there's
        # no clean way of encoding this conditional logic, short of what you see here:
        #
        # We override the AutoSchema inspection class, so we can intercept the CoreAPI Fields it generated,
        # on their way out but before they make their way into the auto-generated api docs.
        #
        # CoreAPI Fields are named tuples, hence the poor man's copy constructor below.

        if path == u'/v1/domains/{domain_name}/access-code-pools' and method == 'POST':
            # find the index of our 'name' field in our fields list
            i = next((i for i, f in enumerate(fields) if (lambda f: f.name == 'name')(f)), -1)
            if i >= 0:
                name_field = fields[i]
                fields[i] = Field(name=name_field.name, location=name_field.location,
                                  schema=name_field.schema, description=name_field.description,
                                  type=name_field.type, example=name_field.example,
                                  required=True)  # all this inspection, just to set this here boolean.
        return fields


class MyNameFilter(FilterSet):
    name = CharFilter(field_name='name', help_text='Filter returned access code pools by name')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name',)


class MyAPIView(...)

    schema = MyViewSchema()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = MyNameFilter
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll get `get_filter_class` in `DjangoFilterBackend`. You need to create a new `FilterBackend` which overrides the `filter_queryset` method.

```
class GETFilterBackend(DjangoFilterBackend):

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return super().filter_queryset(request, queryset, view)
        return queryset


class MyModel(...):
    ...
    filter_backends = (GETFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = MyNameFilter
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I should add, I tried this very solution as well.

The problem is, it doesn't stop the auto-gen docs from listing my query param where it shouldn't be.

I think of this as having two parts:  there's the functionality of the API itself (what it does, does not do).  And then there's the built-in autogen docs.

The above ensures the functionality side.  Queryparam filtering will only happen where it should.  But the docs side remains incorrect.  And this isn't just a matter of ideal documentation, e.g. my queryparam ("name") is masking the same named param in the PUT body.

Comment: Yeah, the above solution will ensure that the filtering is done strictly on `GET` method. Because the filtering will also be applied to `get_object` method which is used by `UpdateModelMixin`. Documentation side I don't think this will work.